# Azure Database for MYSQL frequently connection failed

Tags: azure-cloud-services, azure-database-mysql

I have a Production Database as Azure Database for MYSQL. But its connection failed often. I cant find the issues. Can any one please tell me the reason and how to solve this issues?  [image]

Answer (score 0):

This failed connection occured often, due to blocking hosts. Some document mentioned need to flush hosts on Azure MYSQL Database server.

After i have some changes on Azure Database for MYSQL server, Its working fine. There is no failed connection.

1. First i tried to connect Azure Database for MYSQL Server from my local linux machine. But it shown Access denied. Then i did reset my password in Azure portal. Then i could logon the Azure MYSQL server through my local linux machine.
2. Once logged in to Azure Server, I have used below commands to solve this issue,

   FLUSH HOSTS;

   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Finally resolved this error.